Fabric.js grouping objects must add half the width and height of all the contained objects
I was under the impression that if the x/y origin of the group AND of the embedded object was top/left, then you simply had to add the top/left of the group father to the inner objects, but no... I had to "print_r" it everywhere until I found that...
                    [type] => group
                    [version] => 4.5.0
                    [originX] => left
                    [originY] => top
                    [left] => 40.71
                    [top] => 40.71
                    [width] => 512.38
                    [height] => 345.32

As you can see, group origin X/Y is top/left... And object too:
                    [objects] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => rect
                                    [version] => 4.5.0
                                    [originX] => left
                                    [originY] => top
                                    [left] => -256.19
                                    [top] => -172.66

But I must add the group width/2 to the left, and the group height/2 to the child objects, otherwise all the coordinates are wrong.
Basically, what I mathematically understood is that the coordinates of the children are NOT calculated from the origin of the group, but from the CENTER of the group.
Anyone can confirm or deny this, or tell me what's the best/most correct way to handle it?
Again, if I add width/2 and height/2 of the group to the children it all works fine, but it doesn't make sense since both the group and the children origin state top/left...
